# What is the [sharing] tag for and how could we be more precise?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a [sharing](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharing) tag with two questions:

- [What can be said when people argue that "plants suffer too"?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/341/what-can-be-said-when-people-argue-that-plants-suffer-too)
- [How can I communicate ideas about vegetarianism or veganism to others without appearing like I am imposing it on them?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/269/how-can-i-communicate-ideas-about-vegetarianism-or-veganism-to-others-without-ap)

These questions are both about discussing veg*nism with non-veg*ns. I feel the word [sharing](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharing) fails to capture this idea unambiguously - it could mean almost anything and is likely to be applied quite randomly by users (even with usage guidance - this is not always read!)

If we need a tag for communicating with non-veg*ns, what should we call that tag? I propose we burn the [sharing](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharing) and replace it with something more descriptive like [outreach](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outreach)

Comment: I created the "suffering plants" question and I added the "sharing" tag ONLY because I already saw on the other question you mention, and they looked similar to me. I'm not an english native speaker, so of course a better tagging is more than welcome.

Comment: @Attilio my intention in this post was definitely not to criticise anyone. I assumed that the second post had been tagged following the first. Since "sharing" could be about anything I felt we should come up with something more descriptive.

Comment: I never thought you were criticizing. You are doing excellent work and I'm happy that you're leading the reputation ranking of this group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree. As you said, the [sharing](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharing) tag could be used randomly, without any relevance for the question.

Moreover, I think it is *"too broad"* for the topic of our community as it doesn't help to narrow a question scope.

Using [outreach](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outreach) is more specific and is, for this reason, a good suggestion.

Comment: I have gone ahead and retagged the two posts for now, since it can easily be reverted if people disagree

Comment: I agree, I used tag sharing because of a lack of better word. Outreach works well though.